# nextjs: TypeError: createServer is not a function

Tags: next.js, graphql

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://oneweekgraphql.com/chapters/project-setup/3-install-graphql-yoga-and-configure-api-route):

I am stuck at step 3, which is where the server is defined as follows:

```
import { createServer } from "@graphql-yoga/node";
import { join } from "path";
import { readFileSync } from "fs";

const typeDefs = readFileSync(join(process.cwd(), "schema.graphql"), {
  encoding: "utf-8",
});

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    cart: (_, { id }) => {
      return {
        id,
        totalItems: 0,
      };
    },
  },
};

const server = createServer({
  cors: false,
  endpoint: "/api",
  logging: {
    prettyLog: false,
  },
  schema: {
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
  },
});

export default server;
```

When I try to use that definition and start the local host, I get an error that says:

> TypeError: (0 ,
> *graphql_yoga_node__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0*_.createServer) is not a function     at eval

Can anyone see if this tutorial is now out of date. I can see that I am using next v 13.1.1 and the tutorial uses v12. I've been having an awful time trying to find an explanation of how to use these packages, in their current formats. Is this one now out of date?

Can anyone see how to define a server for next v13?

Comment: The [@graphql-yoga/node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@graphql-yoga/node) package is deprecated. The recommended package is [graphql-yoga](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-yoga#readme)

Comment: Thank you @Phil. I tried replacing it and still get the same error with the way createServer is defined. Thanks for the tip though. I'll do some research on how to convert the definition of the schema before I keep looking for a current tutoiral

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the documentation? They import `createServer` from `node:http`

Comment: yes, I made the file, but I don't know which ones of the options I'm supposed to try and use. Thanks very much just the same.

Comment: _"I made the file,"_... err, what? In case it wasn't clear, I meant [the documentation for graphql-yoga](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-yoga#start)

Comment: Yes - i followed the documentation. it has a list of examples for all different types of packages, one is for next, another for graphql and a range of others. I don't know which of those I'm supposed to choose. Maybe I'm meant to pick express now that the server looks like that format. Thanks - I'll do some research and try to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some change between graph-yoga v2 and v3, you can look this [tutorial](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/yoga-server/docs/migration/migration-from-yoga-v2) to solve it.

Comment: Thanks. I gave up trying to learn graphql. I have tried at least 20 different tutorials and can't find one that's current and a complete demonstration of CRUD steps. I have found that for a different db layer, so will switch to try and learn zod.

Answer (score 0):

For others that might be stuck, this might be a way to define the schema using graphql-yoga (now instead of graphql-yoga/node)

```
import { createSchema, createYoga } from 'graphql-yoga'
import { createServer } from 'node:http'
import { join } from "path";
import { readFileSync } from "fs";

const typeDefs = readFileSync(join(process.cwd(), "schema.graphql"), {
  encoding: "utf-8",
});

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    cart: (_, { id }) => {
      return {
        id,
        totalItems: 0,
      };
    },
  },
};

const yoga = createYoga({
  cors: false,
  endpoint: "/api",
  logging: {
    prettyLog: false,
  },
  schema: createSchema({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
  }),
});

const server = createServer(yoga);
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.info('Server is running on http://localhost:3000/graphql')
});

export default server;
```

Comment: Actually, this is incorrect. I get an error that says resolver is not a function when I try this approach.